# Hide all div element but show first two

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to hide an entire div and only show first 2 entities.

```
<div class="inline-edit-col">
    <span class="title inline-edit-categories-label">Brands</span>
    <ul class="cat-checklist product_brand-checklist">
        <li id="product_brand-3039"><label class="selectit">acer</label></li>
        <li id="product_brand-3040"><label class="selectit">asus</label></li>
    </ul>

    <span class="title inline-edit-categories-label">Product Categories</span>
    <ul class="cat-checklist product_cat-checklist">
        <li id="product_cat-3039"><label class="selectit">mobile</label></li>
        <li id="product_cat-3040"><label class="selectit">car</label></li>
    </ul>

    <span class="title inline-edit-type-label">Product type</span>
    <ul class="cat-checklist product_cat-checklist">
        <li id="product_type-3039"><label class="selectit">electronics</label></li>
        <li id="product_type-3040"><label class="selectit">fashion </label></li>
    </ul>

    {lots of ul li elents as before }
</div>
```

this is the html structure , but i only need to display first two and display other  i.e

```
<div class="inline-edit-col">
    <span class="title inline-edit-categories-label">Brands</span>
    <ul class="cat-checklist product_brand-checklist">
        <li id="product_brand-3039"><label class="selectit">acer</label></li>
        <li id="product_brand-3040"><label class="selectit">asus</label></li>
    </ul>

    <span class="title inline-edit-categories-label">Product Categories</span>
    <ul class="cat-checklist product_cat-checklist">
        <li id="product_cat-3039"><label class="selectit">mobile</label></li>
        <li id="product_cat-3040"><label class="selectit">car</label></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Does any one know how to do this through CSS or Javascript?

i tried the css to hide 3rd,4th,..like

```
.product_cat-checklist{
  display:none;

 }
```

everything hide one by one .But that is not good practice. That's why i am asking here

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes . i tried the css to hide 3rd,4th,..like everything hide one by one .But that is not good practice. That's why i am  asking here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with CSS (no need of Javascript)

```
span:nth-child(n+4) {
  display:none;       // hide all spans starting from 4th child
}
ul:nth-child(n+5) {
  display:none;      // hide all uls starting from 5th child
}
```

How does it work:

```
div               // parent
|-- span          // 1st span - 1st child of parent
|-- ul            // 1st ul   - 2nd child of parent
|-- span          // 2nd span - 3rd child of parent
|-- ul            // 2nd ul   - 4th child of parent
|-- span          // 3rd span - 5th child of parent
|-- ul            // 3rd ul   - 6th child of parent
|-- span          // 4th span - 7th child of parent
|-- ul            // 4th ul   - 8th child of parent
|-- span          // 5th span - 9th child of parent
|-- ul            // 5th ul   - 10th child of parent
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

using jquery [gt](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

```
$('.inline-edit-col > *:gt(1)').hide(); //all childs after 2nd index (zero based index)
```

or

using [array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
$('.inline-edit-col').children().slice(2).hide();
```

Comment: could you please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276905/processing-backwardundo-and-forwardredo-option-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

if you give each span-ul a class "unit"

like:

```
<div class="inline-edit-col">
<div class="unit">
<span class="title inline-edit-categories-label">Brands</span>
<ul class="cat-checklist product_brand-checklist">
    <li id="product_brand-3039"><label class="selectit">acer</label></li>
    <li id="product_brand-3040"><label class="selectit">asus</label></li>
</ul>

</div>
<div class="unit">
<span class="title inline-edit-categories-label">Product Categories</span>
<ul class="cat-checklist product_cat-checklist">
    <li id="product_cat-3039"><label class="selectit">mobile</label></li>
    <li id="product_cat-3040"><label class="selectit">car</label></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

then in css:

```
.inline-edit-col * {
        display:none;
    }

.unit:nth-child(1),.unit:nth-child(2) {
    display:block;
}
```

will do it.
Note that the order is improtant.

Here's a reffernce to CSS selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: div * is all the children of every div